# Obtener datos de un textbox dinámico en ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual, textbox, basic

estoy creando un textbox en tiempo de ejecución, ya eso lo hago bien, lo que tengo la duda es como obtengo los datos de este textbox.

```
        For i = 1 To 9 Step 1
            texto = New TextBox
            texto.ID = "txt" + i.ToString
            texto.Height = 22
            texto.Width = 180
            texto.Text = i.ToString

            pnlCamposTexto.Controls.Add(texto)

        Next



        texto.ID = "txt4"

        MsgBox(texto.Text)
```

El campo **pnlCamposTexto** es un panel

Lo que quiero es por ejemplo en el **MsgBox(texto.Text)** me imprima en pantalla el texto que escribo en el campo txt4 (el que se creo de manera dinamica en el for).

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

supongo te refieres a winforms, puedes intentar hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
TextBox tbx = this.Controls.Find("textBox1", true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
tbx.Text = "found!";

// o esta

Control[] tbxs = this.Controls.Find(txtbox_and_message[0,0], true);
if (tbxs != null && tbxs.Length > 0)
{
    tbxs[0].Text = "Found!";
}
```

Referencia:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_